# Concat 2 fields in JSON using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am using `jq` to reformat my `JSON`.

JSON String:

`{"channel": "youtube", "profile_type": "video", "member_key": "hello"}`

Wanted output:

`{"channel" : "profile_type.youtube"}`

My command:

`echo '{"channel": "youtube", "profile_type": "video", "member_key": "hello"}' | jq -c '. | {channel: .profile_type + "." + .member_key}'`

I know that the command below concatenates the string. But it is not working in the same logic as above:

`echo '{"channel": "youtube", "profile_type": "video", "member_key": "hello"}' | jq -c '.profile_type + "." + .member_key'`

How can I achieve my result using ONLY jq?

Comment: I think I'm trying to do exactly the same thing with my youtube API script ;)

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Use [parentheses](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Parenthesis) around the string concatenation code:

```
echo '{"channel": "youtube", "profile_type": "video", "member_key": "hello"}' \
 | jq '{channel: (.profile_type + "." + .channel)}'
```

Comment: Consider using string interpolation instead, much more cleaner than multiple string concatenations.

Answer (score 99):

Here is a solution that uses string interpolation as [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado) suggested:

```
{channel: "\(.profile_type).\(.member_key)"}
```

e.g.

```
$ jq '{channel: "\(.profile_type).\(.member_key)"}' <<EOF
> {"channel": "youtube", "profile_type": "video", "member_key": "hello"}
> EOF
{
  "channel": "video.hello"
}
```

String interpolation works with the `\(foo)` syntax (which is similar to a shell `$(foo)` call).
See the official [JQ manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)).