# Concatenate name and number field from JSON file

Tags: json, shell, parsing, concatenation, jq

```
{
   "name": "ford",
   "availableVersions": [
      {
         "version": 111,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 122,
         "count": 2
      },
      {
         "version": 133,
         "count": 3
      }
                          ],
       "RealVersion": 133


}
{
   "name": "bmw",
   "availableVersions": [
     {
         "version": 144,
         "count": 1
     },
     {
      "version": 155,
      "count": 3
     }                  ],
     "RealVersion": 120

    }
```

I have this demo.json file now `if (count == 3)` I want to concatenate the name with the version.

So my output should be `[ford:111,ford:133,BMW:155]`. I am using json parsing with jq.

I was using this command which worked fine

```
cat demo2| jq '.name + ": " + (.availableVersions[]|select(.count == 3).version|tostring)'
```

But now i also want one more conditon  `if (count ==3 and version != RealVersion)` then only i want the `version` I tried a lot of command none of them are working. Can someone help me with this?

So EXPECTED OUTPUT =
    `[ford:111,BMW:155]`
So, `ford:133` would not come in the output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concat 2 fields in JSON using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710718/concat-2-fields-in-json-using-jq)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way which captures `.RealVersion` with an `as` earlier in the filter then uses it in the `select`.

```
.name + ": " + (
    .RealVersion as $r
  | .availableVersions[]
  | select(.count == 3 and .version != $r).version 
  | tostring
)
```

Sample output

```
"ford: 111"
"bmw: 155"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDLDoIwELz3K9bGg0TSyOtiwk948EI4FK0GA22kiAfk27GtjdHw0L1sOtPZndnLte8JpyWDNeAtYNVWCFSRHaPFnlUyFxyohGWl4AcQ2tC8oFnBLCeT1BCSFexQr8hB3HgNcQwBUH4E0tgRi1iNcN5Po6mFrKucn5HT963eirUTbeMkqiN2DTRYqPjEWARobdf/7GTFep7nfhDGkYIDi3XuvNr3x9T@n@ogmN2te/oK9nHglxB16PsKWXn/fYQJH2E45sNDXyEmtFE0k6GDQU2H8jeoewI)

Answer (score 0):

Converting multiple input "blobs" to a single output blob requires `-s`|`--slurp`, which is not very memory-efficient. Please be sure this is a requirement before you implement it.

```sh
jq --compact --slurp '
    .[] |= . as $r
        | .availableVersions[]
        | select(.count == 3 and .version != $r.RealVersion)
        | "\($r.name):\(.version)"
'
```

Output:

```
["ford:111","bmw:155"]
```