# parsing json and print only values

Tags: json, jq, jsonparser

I have this json object like this :

```
 [ {
    "name": "ACCOUNT-V1",
    "version": "1.3.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "IDENTIFIER-V1",
    "version": "1.1.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "LOCATION-V1",
    "version": "1.6.0"
  }
]
```

I'd like to parse and print like this

```
ACCOUNT-V1 1.3.0
IDENTIFIER-V1 1.1.0
LOCATION-V1 1.6.0
```

tried with

```
cat json_content.json | jq ' .[] | .name .version'
```

just getting empty array [] in output

Comment: Show us what you have tried with jq, and then explain what it's not doing right.

Comment: The printed output spec is unclear. The first field is delimited by 2 spaces and the second two are delimited by 1 space. Regardless, you probably want to start by extracting the two fields and joining them: `.[] | "\(.name) \(.version)"`, yes? (you can use `-r` to remove the quotes in the output)

Comment: thanks @ggorlen, it worked, I would like to accept your answer

Comment: Seems like a dupe of [Concat 2 fields in JSON using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45527623/6243352)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq --raw-output '.[] | "\(.name) \(.version)"'
```

Where

- `.[]` Loops over the array
- `"\(.name) \(.version)"` creates a string with `name` and `version` key
  <sup>[Using string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example69)</sup>
- `--raw-putput` ensures no quotes on the output

---

[Try it online!](https://jqplay.org/s/1Yy_pmsESE)

Answer (score 0):

In JSON :

- [ .. ] is for array
- { .. } is object

So if you put your json to a variable like

```
const jsx = [ {
    "name": "ACCOUNT-V1",
    "version": "1.3.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "IDENTIFIER-V1",
    "version": "1.1.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "LOCATION-V1",
    "version": "1.6.0"
  }
];
```

It will be :

- jsx[0].name = "ACCOUNT-V1"
- jsx[2].version = "1.6.0"
- and so on